# antenna configuration of wireless card in MacBook Pro?

Tags: networking, antenna, 802.11ac

Does anybody know what is the antenna configuration of wireless card in MacBook Pro? I wonder if it is 11ac 1x1, 2x2 or 3x3?

**MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)**

> Interfaces: en0:   Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x133)
>   Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.68.1a4)   MAC
>   Address:  ac:bc:32:77:b8:05   Locale: ETSI   Country Code:    NC
>   Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n/ac   Supported Channels: 1, 2, 3,
>   4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100,
>   104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140   Wake On
>   Wireless: Supported   AirDrop:    Supported   AirDrop Channel:    44   Auto
>   Unlock:   Supported   Status: Connected

Appreciate anyone can help.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Ya, there's only 10 or more models spanning decades sharing that name, "Macbook Pro" is just a tad imprecise.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3x3:3 802.11ac. Broadcom 4360. Supports 80MHz-wide channels and short guard interval for a 1300Mbps max PHY rate.

By the way, 3x3 is not an antenna configuration, it is the configuration of transmit and receive *radio chains*. Antennas are just passive chunks of metal. Even old single chain radios would often have a main and an auxiliary antenna for diversity; the fact that they had two *antennas* didn't increase their max transmit rate. So you really want to know about radio chains, not antennas.

Comment: What does the `:3` signify in `3x3:3`? Also, is this true of any Broadcom 4360, or is it configurable by the system integrator? IOW, did you have to know some details about the Macbook Pro implementation specifically to find the data in your answer, or was just knowing the WiFi chipset enough?

Comment: @allquixotic The :3 is the number of spatial streams supported. Extra radio chains can be used for beamforming instead of spatial streams, so it's useful to know that your 3x3 really supports 3 spatial streams. Broadcom makes a 4350 if you only want a 2x2, but it is possible that a given system design doesn't use the full capabilities of a given chipset, so knowing that something has a 4360 doesn't guarantee that it uses the full 3x3:3 capabilities of the 4360. I *do* know that the rMBPs since mid 2013 support 3 spatial streams though. Support for the 1300Mbps PHY rate (MCS 9x3) gives it away.